# Store mysql Data in variable Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql on node.js to get an id from some table .And now i wants to store that id in variable.

```
con.query("SELECT user_id FROM owners where id =?", [ownerId] , function (err, result, fields) {
    let id=result;
    console.log(id);
    if(err) throw err;
    //console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
```

I works perfectly and gets data from server but it stores th value in id is like `[ RowDataPacket { user_id: 1642 } ]`. But i want my id as only "1642" so that i can use some conditions. Kindl help

Comment: What about `result[0]. user_id`???

Comment: let me check Thanks

Comment: still same result [ RowDataPacket { user_id: 1642 } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for the following:

```
var parsedResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
let id = parsedResult[0].user_id;
```

Comment: Worked For me thanks man

Comment: Glad to help! Have a happy coding!!!